# How to PDF render Quarto books with dynamic content?

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, rstudio, quarto

I am writing my thesis using a Quarto book in HTML, which has some dynamic content (leaflet maps, plotly dynamic graphs). However, eventually, I will need to export the book in PDF/LaTeX, or at least Word (and then I can copy and paste into LaTeX).

When I try to export to PDF I of course run into this error:

> Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting pdf
> output. Please change the output type of this document to HTML.
> Alternatively, you can allow HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding
> this option to the YAML front-matter of your rmarkdown file:
>
> always_allow_html: true
>
> Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML
> formats.

I did try to add the `always_allow_html: true` in my YAML file, but I get the same exact error. I also tried the [conditional rendering](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/conditional.html) with `{.content-hidden unless-format="pdf"}`, but I can't seem to get it working.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Can you try `{.content-hidden unless-format="html"}` instead?

Comment: I just tried putting ::: {.content-hidden unless-format="html"} {r} R CODE ::: and it does produce a PDF (obviously with no content, but I think I need to put another  code to produce a static plot and hide it when the format is HTML. However, if render to HTML I don't see anymore my dynamic content. I just see the code block

Comment: Adding a reproducible example with your question that will address the problem would be helpful to suggest a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.content-visible when-format="html"` and `.content-visible when-format="pdf"` works very smoothly.

---

````
---
title: "Conditional Rendering"
format: 
  html: default
  pdf: default
---

## Conditional Content in Quarto

::: {.content-visible when-format="html"}

```{r}
#| message: false

library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p <-  p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))

ggplotly(p)
```


```{r}
#| message: false
#| fig-pos: "H"
#| fig-width: 4
#| fig-height: 3

library(leaflet)

# took this example from leaflet docs
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map

```

:::


::: {.content-visible when-format="pdf"}

```{r}

library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p <-  p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))

p
```

:::
````

Comment: I am trying the same thing, but if I make a div that is not visible in HTML, the render works and correctly does not show my div. When I do the opposite, which is hiding a leaflet map in PDF and rendering the PDF, it does not work. I will try to create a reproducible example now. Also is there a way to see which exact code line stops the rendering?

Comment: Also, just tried your code on a new document and I get the same error, unless I add always_allow_html: true
However, adding this to my own code still produces that error

Comment: Ok, the solution is adding to every page: 
---
always_allow_html: true
---
and then using conditional formatting as in your example.

Comment: @Roberto, I have tried the code above for quarto book too, it works without using  `always_allow_html: true` for both pdf and html as intended.

Comment: Then it must be something in my RStudio settings? Because I started a completely new quarto document (independent from the quarto book project) and I was getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this one too. I'm currently checking the output format of pandoc globally

````r
```{r, echo = F}
output <- knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
```
````

and then evaluate chunks conditionally:

(leaflet example from [here](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/widgets/htmlwidgets.html).)

````
```{r, echo = F, eval = output != "latex"}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")  
```
````

This is optional if you want a note on a missing component in the PDF version:

````
```{r, echo = F, eval = output == "latex", results = "asis"}
cat("\\textit{Please see the HTML version for interactive content.}")
```
````

**Edit**

I just checked, this also works with Quarto documents for me using the below YAML header.

```yaml
---
title: "Untitled"
format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
---
```

Comment: I did try this, but:
> Error: object "output" not found
>Error in yaml::yaml.load(yaml, eval.expr = TRUE) : 
>Could not evaluate expression: output != "latex"
>Calls: .main ... parse_block -> partition_yaml_options -> <Anonymous>

I did put the output code though, I don't know why it says not found

Comment: It works like a charm for me in a plain new quarto book project. Did you copy and these blocks in `index.qmd`? You don't have to modify `_quarto.yml`.

Comment: I pasted them in my index.qmd before anything else

Comment: Did you really do these steps in a new book project (RStudio: New Project > New Directory > Quarto Book)? If so I recommend updating Quarto and RStudio (https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/). It's hard to provide further guidance without any info on software version or a reproducible example.

Comment: To test this, I did not create a book but a plain new Quarto document. The error is always 
Error: object "output" not found
Error in yaml::yaml.load(yaml, eval.expr = TRUE) : 
Could not evaluate expression: output == "latex"
Calls: .main ... parse_block -> partition_yaml_options -> <Anonymous>

Comment: I just tried with (non-book) Quarto document and it works too for me (see the YAML header in my edit). As mentioned before: it is hard to help further without knowing package/RStudio versions. Could you provide these?

Comment: I just copied your header as well, but I get the same error.  The R studio version is: RStudio 2022.07.1+554 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (7872775ebddc40635780ca1ed238934c3345c5de, 2022-07-22) for macOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_5_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.10 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
I am not sure how to check the quarto version though. However, if I add the always_allow_html: true in every page of my book everything works.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited chunk options in my answer. Could please you retry?

Comment: This does correctly work now! So I need to add the expression inside the {r} opening?

Comment: Yes – it seems that the "Quarto way" to specify chunk options (https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html) does not play nicely in every case. My last edit is the "knitr way". :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use constructs like below

```
p <- ggplot()
if (interactive() || opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") == "html") {
  ggplotly(p)
} else {
  p
}
```